# Summation of specified numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm confused by this Question (probably because English is not my 1st language)

*Add all those positive integers less or equal n which are a multiples of 3 or of 5.*

There's an example for n = 15 equals 50.

But shouldn't it be 15+12+10+9+6+5+3 = 60?

Comment: You are right, it is 60.

Comment: Thanks. I thought i went insane over such a simple question.